# Imgur.com issues

Tags: support, imgur

There seems to be an issue uploading images from webapps.stackexchange.com at present.

I'm pretty sure it is a problem with imgur.com so I doubt anything can be done here.

It is quite annoying as there is no backup plan if imgur.com isn't available.  You just can't upload pictures.

**Edit**

Ok it appears you can display images from an existing URL using the img tag - which I forgot you could use.

It would be nice that if the upload fails it would prompt you to do it the "old fashioned" way.

Comment: "You just cant upload pictures." Well, that's how it used to be until August 13 :)

Comment: Imgur is pretty slow. Please fix it.

Comment: looks like its back to normal now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* upload images wherever you want and link to them here. You just have to type the markup (or HTML `<img>` tag) yourself, as the toolbar button is now limited to doing imgur uploads.

Note that this is not *preferred* for various reasons, such as link rot as well as the HTTPS changeover (all image links must now be HTTPS, so your image host has to support that). So if you *can* use the built-in uploader, definitely prefer doing so.

Comment: Markup: `![alt text](image_url "mouseover")`

Comment: The easiest way around imgur is to use Ctrl-L to link to the image, then prefix the link markdown with an exclamation mark.